# Replace NA by largest factor count of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

Okey, after staring for hours at a dplyr cheat sheet I'm now finally giving up and asking my question here.

I have data in this form:

```
ID    Material    Supplier
1     a           01
2     b           02
3     NA          01
4     NA          02
4     a           02
4     b           02
```

Now, I want to replace the NAs with the most common material grouped by supplier. I'm using this code to count the most common materials and place the count in a data frame b but I want to do the replacement at the same time.

```
b <- a[which(!is.na(a$material)),] %>%
              group_by(supplier, material) %>%
              summarise(n = n()) %>%
              group_by(supplier) %>%
              filter(n == max(n))
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does it need to be a `dplyr` solution?

Comment: here: `merge(a, b, by = 'supplier') %>%
    mutate(material = coalesce(material.x, material.y)) %>%
    select(supplier, id, material)`

Comment: in case you are also interested in a `library(data.table)` solution: `setDT(df)[, Material := ifelse(is.na(Material), names(which.max(table(Material))), Material), by = Supplier][]`

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I'm going to go with the below answer this time, makes the most sense to me right now since I've not familiarized myself with the data.table package yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using `table` within the `dplyr` function:

```
a %>%  
group_by(Supplier) %>%
mutate(Material=ifelse(is.na(Material),names(sort(table(Material),dec=T))[1],Material))
```

This returns:

```
    ID Material Supplier
  <int>    <chr>    <int>
1     1        a        1
2     2        b        2
3     3        a        1
4     4        b        2
5     4        a        2
6     4        b        2
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to convert material into character first for this to work, but it worked.
One addition is that this should be prefixed with "a <-" so that the new data is stored in the data frame, and not just printed out.

Comment: I'm having trouble using this with numerical values...any idea why? It doesn't produce an error message but it doesn't replace the NAs either :(

Comment: I've tried it on a column with 1s and 2s instead of a and b, and it works. Note however that the resulting column will become of type character, because we are taking the names of the table. If you want to keep it as numeric, just do `as.numeric(names(sort(table(Material),dec=T))[1])`.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized why it isn't working for me. The supplier groups that I'm trying to get information from is all NA for material, which of course produces the result of NAs.... duh!